# ANT Running error

Tags: ant, testng

I am running Ant using Testng and While compiling and running ant via command prompt or eclipse getting the following error... Pls help me how to rectify the problem.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: There are no errors in your screenshot. There are several _warnings_, but warnings are different than errors. Which specific warnings do you want fixed?

Comment: There is one error java.lang.NullPointerExeception at run time... what is this error realated to?  How can I get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 0):

While runing Ant using testng I was getting java.lang.nullpointerexception error. after checking all my code multiiple times there was not a problem in the code or java and ant configuration. The error was in the XML where the suite was written like this Suite.../Suite and it should be like suite.../suite, only S was capital for suite in xml which has given that particular error.